# Different size JPGs for Smart TV slide show

Tags: adobe-indesign, jpg

I have created a document in InDesign with images and some text. I have then printed to PDF and then saved the PDF as JPG files. When I connect my USB to the Smart TV all the jpgs are different sizes and have various different borders. Why is this? Please help?

Comment: Are they the same size? Does the aspect ratio match the tv's aspect ratio? — I might be wrong, but I believe tv's like to stretch usb fed images to fit the screen... maybe there are other options, but if they are stretched to fit the screen and if the image aspect ratio doesn't match the tv, you will see black border on either top and bottom or the sides.

Comment: The document I made in indesign is exactly the same size, the images within each page is not. But when I export to pdf and then to jpg they all look identical however on the tv screen some fit the screen and some are smaller? How can I make them all uniform?

Comment: Laura, what size are the jpegs? Check they are the same size in pixel dimensions. If not, then that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks Billy. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Most TVs have an options for [Full], [Letterbox], [Panel], etc.. these typically alter how the image is displayed being either stretched to fill the screen or not. Chances are your issues are related to the tv, not InDesign or your jpgs. I've voted to close this since this is regarding *your* local equipment and can't be solved on a message board.

Comment: It's kinda hard to blindly point out how to fix this issue. I don't think we can say much more than what's already been said: Make sure your images are all the right size/aspect ratio. If you are working on a Mac, you can see the jpg size if you select it and press `cmd+i`.   and also make sure the Crop and Aspect ratio in the tv is proper. It's possible the remote has specific buttons for rotating through the different options or it could be a thing in the tv settings. I'm leaning towards the issue being what Scott pointed out.

Comment: Laura, check the size dimensions. If you are using Windows, right click the jpeg file, choose Properties > Details - the size in pixels should be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

A PDF can have elements outside the visible area, so probably your PDF have that. But without seeing the files, or knowing your process to move from PDF to JPG it is hard to know.

But a better process would be to export the screens directly from InDesign.

File > Export > and choose JPG.